# Get the result of sim in matlab code with input parameter returns not found

Tags: matlab, simulation, circuit

I have this circuit in Matlab simulation

[image]

As you can see I have R7 variable in my picture .

I want to run this simulink using Matlab script as you can see here :

```
simOut = sim('ehsaaan.slx','R7','1e-100')
```

As you can see I pass R7 to my circuit. But when I run the code I get this error :

```
Error using main
block_diagram does not have a parameter named 'R7'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SimScape parameters maynot be acessible as `sim` name-valus pairs. You can use `set_param` to set the resistance parameter `R` as follows:

```
set_param('ehsaaan/R7','R','1e-100')
simOut = sim('ehsaaan.slx')
```